# Twitter integration(android)- api v1.1

Tags: android, twitter

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=screen-name&include_entities=true

is not working.

Getting Bad Authentication data error.

Twitter integration is also getting same error. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use oAuth.

use for example this class - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth
also must create app to get needed KEYs ($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret).
and to get for example tweets from timeline just execute this code

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs/twitteroauth.php');
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    $response = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => $twitter_name));
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($response,1).'</pre>';
```